# Background Image Positioning

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, css, background-image

I have created a sprite which includes a whole set of icons which I use in my web application. However, I have run into a problem when styling links. I know with CSS I can manipulate the size of the link and move its background image (the sprite) around, so I only display the icon I want within the sprite. This works great for links with no text. However, if I have a link with a background image and additional text, that is where I run into problems.

Take a look at these images, which will explain my dilemma:

- Icon sprite: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/vN74tYI2lsdjOCpvdLjdPBV2JJooBc4dMF1MOKsl3b4?feat=directlink
- Dilemma: https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/UkC1dP7Fzxv02f_xjX-AEBV2JJooBc4dMF1MOKsl3b4?feat=directlink

I know I can "clip" the background image in CSS3, but I am trying to avoid that at this point, because I know mainly older browsers [like IE8 X(] will be accessing the site, and won't see this change. Is there a way to do this without placing an additional tag, such as a `<span>` tag inside of each link and styling those? I've seen examples where I can use an AJAX library, like jQuery, to help with this, but that is alot of sweat for a small task.

I hope that wasn't confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put blank space in your sprite where you need to. That should do the trick.
Just like this one > http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/youtube-sprite.png

Comment: Hmm... great point! I see their sprite eliminates all intruding icons in the "x" direction. The only problem is, in some cases, I may have containers styled with this sprite where its height (a.k.a. "y" direction) may change. Is there a >= CSS2 property or image adjustment which I could apply to remedy that issue, as well?

Comment: I don't know of a property than can help you with this, I think the trick is in the sprite, the way you position your element within it. 

You can find other example where they've put white space in the y direction:
http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/images/css-sprites/digg.gif

Comment: Ah... okay. Thanks, lipelip! Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That is actually pretty simple with jQuery: Just assign all such elements a common class like `sprite`. Now you can check if it's IE8 and run this code:

```
$('.sprite').toggleClass('sprite').prepend('<span class="sprite"/>')
```

That creates a `span` with the `sprite` class. With some clever CSS, you should be able to move the background to the element with the `sprite` class.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't even think of that. That's a good point, because may of these tricky links all have the same base class to define its width, height and such. If possible, I would like to massage the image/CSS first. But if that doesn't work, I'll use your suggestion.